# Android Version Controll Error. ThemeWrapper Error in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi I found this error in my app. It is crashed when I clicked my navigation header.I want to go to profile fragment when I click my header.It works in KitKat.But it was crushed in lollipop and higher. I got this error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.example.chitsumoe.good_friend.MainActivity, but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.

This is my main activity code.

```
package com.example.chitsumoe.good_friend;

import android.net.Uri;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,InformTrackFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction homefragmentTransaction    = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    homefragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, homefragment);
    homefragmentTransaction.commit();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

public void goToProfile(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction profileFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    profileFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, profileFragment);
    profileFragmentTransaction.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.nav_home)
    {
        HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction homefragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        homefragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, homefragment);
        homefragmentTransaction.commit();
        // return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_findfriend)
    {
        FindFriendFragment findFriendFragment=new FindFriendFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction findfriendfragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        findfriendfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, findFriendFragment);
        findfriendfragmentTransaction.commit();
        // return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_friendrequest)
    {
        FriendRequestFragment friendRequestFragment=new FriendRequestFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction friendrequestfragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        friendrequestfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, friendRequestFragment);
        friendrequestfragmentTransaction.commit();
        //return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_informtrack)
    {

        InformTrackFragment informtrackfragment=new InformTrackFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction informtrackfragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        informtrackfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,informtrackfragment);
        informtrackfragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_setting)
    {
        SettingFragment settingFragment=new SettingFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction settingfragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        settingfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, settingFragment);
        settingfragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

This is my profileFragment code.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

What is wrong with Lollipop?

This is entire crash log.

> 04-12 05:28:03.835 9141-9141/com.example.chitsumoe.good_friend E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.chitsumoe.good_friend, PID: 9141
>                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.example.chitsumoe.good_friend.MainActivity, but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: please post the entire crash log

Comment: I had added log. thx

Comment: @SMR You can check now

Answer (score 2):

for me it was caused using
`android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` in child views in navigation header xml.

This caused error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutNavHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_header"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

changing to this solved problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutNavHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_header"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```